# Cosmoem Evolution

Tags: pokemon-go

If I evolve a Cosmoem into a Solgaleo, is there a way to get Lunala? Because my goal is to complete the Pokedex, if I evolve my Cosmoem into Solgaleo, what are the ways to get a Lunala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cosmog line can be traded, so if you find someone who is willing to trade you their Lunala (or a Cosmog/Cosmoem) for your Solgaleo (or anything else valuable you may have), you can get the entry in your dex that way.

Otherwise, provided you didn't complete the limited-time research line, the only thing you can do is wait. Cosmog has already been released twice and will be available on more occasions in the future, as its shiny form has not yet been made available.